# Rails: Parsing a text string and loading child tables on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application I have three models: **articles**, **sentences** and a join model **article_sentences**.

The **@article.article** field contains several paragraphs of text. Sentences are delimited by full stops and there are also blank lines.

When the user creates or edits an article, I would like behind the scenes code to parse the value of the text in **@article.article** and create an entry for each full stop delimited sentence in the **sentences** table.

Would this type of "post-save" code go in the **create** method in the articles controller? Any suggestions on how to do the parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any place where you store the (modified) article, is a good place to parse the (updated) contents.

So in the regular situation that would be in

- `create` method, as it stores a new article
- `update` method as it stores an updated version of the article (dpending on your requirements, you might remove the sentences *before* storing the updated version and *parse* the article afterwards

If you do not use the default REST implementation you need to find your custom locations where you store/update articles.

Comment: I see that's very helpful. So perhaps I would loop through the content of the text and call Sentence.new for each sentence?

Comment: Something like that. But I guess you also need to check whether the sentence what already added or not and either increase the usage count or add a new sentence to your database. But that depends on your application requirements, I suppose.